# project structure and call redirects

Tags: php, apache, project-organization

I am working on a small project to maintain email lists.  I am not using any frameworks for this project.  I am planning to use phing for deployment.
I have two questions:
 - Is this a good project structure for a simple project.
 - How do I redirect the calls to my view files in src folder. For ex: http://localhost/test/mydashboard.php since the view files are in src folder. Is some sort of symlink or mod rewrites needed? 
- somewhat related to my second question is should the folder structure be any different on production for this project.

[image]

Comment: Subjective question is subjective. However objectively having logic in your doc root is bad mkay

Comment: I would recommend using a "php router" to redirect calls to your view files.  It'll also require a slightly customized .htaccess file, but using a front controller would help you to centralize the redirect code into one or more index.php files.  Also, you should consider using a "class autoloader" so you won't have to manually take care of each file's include dependencies.

Comment: MingShun.. I am using composer autoloader.. and it is working great!! Just not sure how to redirect the calls.  some code sample would be helpful.